# print to stdout by a variable

Tags: bash, shell, stdout

The following works:

```
[nir page]$ echo 1 2>&1 >&1
1
```

But when I use a variable it does not:

```
[nir page]$ out="&1"
[nir -page]$ echo $out
&1
[nir page]$ echo 1 2>$out >$out
[nir page]$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Idea is to send output to `/dev/null` except when I ask to stdout.

Comment: You could assign `/dev/stdout` instead of `&1` to the variable.

Comment: `&1` is not a value that can be used with `2>`. `>&` is an operator that takes 2 and 1 as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are assuming that parts of the syntax can be stored in a variable. They can't. `&` has to be literally typed on the line, it can't be in a variable.

> Idea is to send output to /dev/null except when I ask to stdout.

You use file descriptors for that.

```
if when I dont ask; then
   exec 1>/dev/null 2>&1
fi
echo 1
```

Or use linux `/dev/*` files:

```
out=/dev/stdout  # or /dev/null
echo 1 >"$out"
```